# writing and reading png images must be same for different java versions

Tags: java, mysql, png

I serialized png files by using

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", b);
return b.toByteArray();
```

and wrote the result array to a database column.

Now I've changed the java version from oracle 8 to openjdk 11, and the serialized result differs. 
This won't be a problem for the picture itself, but I need to have the same serialized data for all my png pictures (because I create a certification of all serialized column data for each row), for different Java versions.

Is there somewhere a configuration possibility, where I can exactly say, how the png file should look like - and is it possible to have it look like in (default) java oracle 8?

I've tried to copy the PNGImageReader and the PNGImageWriter from the ImageIO package, but it uses com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.InputStreamAdapter and further dependencies of that package, which are not declared to be visible.

Comment: I doubt that the serialized result would differ, there is no reason for that. Did any of your code change? Can you re-check that the image data changes regardless of the other factors (such as database interaction etc)? What data type does your column have?

Comment: This sample code:

`public static byte[] serializeImage(BufferedImage img) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(img, "png", b);
                b.flush();
                b.close();
                return b.toByteArray();
 }
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./Clown.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
System.out.printf("size is: " + serializeImage(image, iw).length + "\n");
`
gives different result when I run it with different java versions.

Answer (score 0):

PNG encoding has several parameters, mainly the "filtering" (pixel prediction) strategy and settings for ZLIB compression. It's practically hopeless to require that different PNG coders produce the same binary file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. I solved the problem by using the same encoder  for all platforms.